# Are the results of training a H2O autoencoder on the same data and same hyperparameters supposed to always be the same?

Tags: r, h2o, autoencoder

Good day! I was training a h2o autoencoder and everytime I did so, the anomaly results (reconstruction score) of the variables I received would always be different, although the data I am using was more or less always the same. I was just wondering if this was supposed to be the case? Thank you!

I implemented the h2o.DeepLearningEstimator in R

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `reproducible` parameter of the autoencoder in [the h2o-3 documentation](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/deep-learning.html?highlight=autoencoder):

> reproducible: Specify whether to force reproducibility on small data.
> If this option is enabled, the model takes more time to generate
> because it uses only one thread. This option defaults to False
> (disabled).

Also set the `seed` parameter to a fixed integer value.